# How can I retrieve a list of all users in Smooch

Tags: smooch, supportkit

I see on Smooch there is a way to retrieve all messages for a given user, using `GET /v1/appusers/{smoochId|userId}/messages` but **how can I get a list of all users** (or, at least, all userIds) who are currently using my app. There doesn't seem to be an endpoint for that in the API. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible at this point. However, you can subscribe to webhooks (listening for the `message:appUser` event) and keep track of your users yourself.

See https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#webhooks for the details about webhooks.

Comment: I see, thanks. Are there any plans to add this soon? Seems like a pretty common use case.

Comment: I know it's on the roadmap, but I don't know the priority of it over our other planned features.

Comment: Hey @Marc-AntoineLemieux, I'm also waiting for this feature. Is there a date for this feature yet, also, where can I get the smooch roadmap?